# How to generate RSA PKCS5 keypair in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I need to create a set of RSA keys (public+private) on the client (javascript), send it to the server (Ruby) that uses those keys to encrypt data, which is sent to a mobile device which needs to decrypt using the same generated private key.

I started by implementing the server-side and encrypt using [OpenSSL](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html)

> public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(Base64.decode64(user_public_key))
>
> encrypted_data = public_key.public_encrypt(data)

For decrypting the data on mobile, I had to use PKCS5 padding for the decryption to work, due to OpenSSL using this padding protocol.

Now I want to create the RSA keys on Javascript, but I fail to find a matching library that uses the same RSA PKCS5 protocol.

I found suggestions to use [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) but this uses OAEP rather than PKCS5.

Can anyone please suggest which library I can use with JavaScript in order to create a set of RSA keys that match the encryption protocol used by ruby's OpenSSL and the mobile libraries?

Comment: We cannot understand from the question how OpenSSL is used. Are you sure it is OpenSSL **padding**? PKCS#5 specifies password based encryption and - as part of that - it also includes a simple padding scheme.

Comment: You presumably don't mean PKCS#5, but PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. The WebCrypto API indeed supports only OAEP for encryption/decryption and no PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. The recommendation of libraries is off topic on SO, but here is [a list](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441) with JavaScript crypto libaries, e.g. [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) is very powerful, but maybe you may find a smaller library that meets your requirements as well. Note that padding generally doesn't matter for key generation, but only during encryption/decryption.